# Retrieve empty result as 0 sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to pull a team's win/loss record, in this instance team 1. There are multiple formats teams can play, and the record groups these accordingly. It work's perfectly except if a team hasn't played in a draw in a certain format (probably does it for wins too, but I don't have any winless teams in the db), then it refuses to get any data for that format. I need to it to return a zero for the draw and thus display the rest of the results for that format. The query is below:

```
SELECT matches.format, count(id) as played, a.wins, b.draws, count(id)-a.wins-b.draws as loss
FROM matches 

INNER JOIN (SELECT format, count(id) as wins 
FROM matches 
WHERE winner=1
GROUP BY format) as a ON matches.format=a.format

INNER JOIN (SELECT format, count(id) as draws 
FROM matches 
WHERE hometeam=1 
AND winner=-1 
OR awayteam=1  
AND winner=-1) as b ON matches.format=b.format

WHERE matches.hometeam=1
OR matches.awayteam=1
GROUP BY format
```

This returns

```
format played wins draws loss
  1      14     9   1     4
```

but completely neglects that this team has also played 6 games with format '2', winning 4 and losing 2 with no draws. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use isnull(count(id), 0) as draws
The exact syntax difference base on your database

Comment: What does the following mean? `...except if a team hasn't played in a draw in a certain format...`  Can you post your source data as well as your desired output?

Comment: Which DBMS? Your query can be a lot more concise. Off the top of my head, the INNER JOINS are removing results. Make them OUTER LEFT joins.

Comment: @AbeMiessler you want all 95 rows?

Comment: No, a subset plus the desired output for that subset will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to your question is `but with no draws`.  It sounds like you should be using an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT matches.format, count(id) as played, coalesce(a.wins,0) wins, coalesce(b.draws,0), count(id)-coalesce(a.wins,0)-coalesce(b.draws,0) as loss
FROM matches 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT format, count(id) as wins 
        FROM matches 
        WHERE winner=1
        GROUP BY format
    ) as a ON matches.format=a.format
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT format, count(id) as draws 
        FROM matches 
        WHERE hometeam=1 
            AND winner=-1 
            OR awayteam=1  
            AND winner=-1
    ) as b ON matches.format=b.format
WHERE matches.hometeam=1
    OR matches.awayteam=1
GROUP BY matches.format
```

Be careful with your use of AND... OR  -- you probably need parentheses...

Now for the optimization:

```
SELECT format, 
    count(id) played,
    sum(if(winner=1,1,0)) wins,
    sum(if(winner=-1,1,0)) draw,
    count(id)-sum(if(winner=1,1,0))-sum(if(winner=-1,1,0)) loss
FROM matches
WHERE hometeam=1 OR awayteam=1
GROUP BY format
```

Comment: While that does return the row when it is null, it returns it as null not 0 when it is null, therefore both draws and losses are null

Comment: @user1672694 -- just use coalesce(field,0) instead.  That will return 0 if the field is null.

Comment: If you mean this: SELECT format, coalesce(count(id),0) as draws it doesn't work

Comment: @user1672694 -- not what I meant.  Count(id) should NEVER be null since id is coming from your matches table... I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT matches.format,
         count(id) as played,
         count(case when winner=1 then 1 end) wins,
         ifnull(count(case when winner=-1 then 1 end),0) draw,
         count(case when winner not in (1,-1) then 1 else 0 end) loss
    FROM matches
   WHERE matches.hometeam=1 OR matches.awayteam=1
GROUP BY format
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just returns the played matches for wins, draws and losses